# How to set maxWorkerThreads for WEBPAI Hosted in Windows service

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

We have WEBApi (dotnet framework 4.6.1) hosted in windows service.

Now we need to setup maxWorkerThreads and maxIOThreads based on number of cores for performance tuning..

Is it possible to setup this information in app.config file itself? Or Please guide me to right place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set these numbers in `machine.config` file. The path is `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config`. Open `machine.config` file and  search `<processModel>`.

You will find an item like this:

[image]

This means that the asp.net framework will automatically configure the asp.net thread parameters for you to handle concurrent requests according to different situations. It is set on a per CPU basis. Default for single CPU is 20/20. So you don't need to set it.

[processModel Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/7w2sway1(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: thank you.. I should enable performance counters and see the number of threads and number of active users connected. because lot of users are complaining that the service is not giving data.. Our web api is calling an internal web service  (soap) and giving response to the clients. due to this lot of errors are logged into my catch block like thread abort exception and connection timeout.  Once I got approval to work on this issue, i will comeback to you... Thank you for the reply..